# google chrome, can't fix img width, height

Tags: jquery, google-chrome

if i have an image element where i'm not set height and width, like this

```
<img id="img" src="image.jpg" />
```

and then when i try to get

```
img_height = $("#img").attr("height");
```

it returns `0`.

how can i get the size of image in google chrome.

Thanks

Update:

`height = $("#img").height();` doesn't work too...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the [`.height()`](http://api.jquery.com/height/) and [`.width()`](http://api.jquery.com/width/) methods, like this:

```
var height = $("#img").height();
var width= $("#img").width();
```

Also make sure you're running this in `$(window).load()` rather than `$(document).ready()` so that the image is loaded.

Comment: @Syom - Are you running it after the image is loaded?

Comment: @Syom: He means `$(window).load()`, not `$(document).ready()`

Comment: @Syom - That doesn't mean it's loaded :) see my answer above, you need to do this in `window.onload` when images are loaded.  If you're creating the image dynamically, you'll need another approach.

Comment: @Syom, the image is not loaded at `$(document).ready(...`, you need to run it at `$(document).load(...`)

Comment: @kingjeffrey - It has to be `window`, `document` has no load method ;)

Comment: @Nick, yes, sorry: `$(window).load(...)`. Cut and Paste got the best of me.

Answer (score 4):

You can use jQuery's `.height()` & `.width()`

**EDIT:**  Now with caching to make the internet a better place:

```
var img_height, img_width, the_img = $("#img");

img_height = the_img.height();
img_width = the_img.width();
```

Answer (score 1):

That returned 0 because the attribute 'height' is not set. Try this jQuery function instead:

```
img_height = $("#img").height();
```

Answer (score 0):

Does this work in other browsers? Your HTML does not indicate a specified "height" attribute.